# Limit of $\frac1x \sum_{z=1}^{z=x}\ln(z)$ as $x$ approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

As I was reading a book on market microstructure, I came across an equation:

$\text{Price} = m_0 + \frac{2G_1(1+\gamma)}{Q}\sum_{L=1}^{Q}\ln L$.

The book then proceeds to say, for $Q\gg 1$:

$\text{Price }\approx m_0 + 2G_1(1+\gamma)(\ln Q - 1)$

Hence, the book implies $\frac{\sum_{z=1}^{x}\ln (z)}{x} \to \ln(x)-1$ as $x \to \infty$.

So far, I assumed that as $\sum_{z=1}^{x}\ln(z) \to \ln(x)$ as  $x \to \infty$.

Assuming that is correct, I am having trouble for the final step. How does $\frac{\ln(x)}{x} \to\ln x-1$ ? And any help will go a long way. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we have $$\sum_{n\leq x}\log\left(n\right)=\sum_{n\leq x}1\cdot\log\left(n\right)=x\log\left(x\right)-\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{t}dt$$ where $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor $ is the [floor function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html) and so, using $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor =x+O\left(1\right)$, we get $$\sum_{n\leq x}\log\left(n\right)=x\log\left(x\right)-x+O\left(\log\left(x\right)\right)$$ hence $$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}\log\left(n\right)=\color{red}{\log\left(x\right)-1+o\left(1\right)}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Marco Cantarini. It really helped.

Comment: @vpy You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that, since $\ln(x) + \ln(y) = \ln(xy)$, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{z=1}^{x} \ln (z) & = \ln(1) + \ln(2) + ... + \ln(x) \\
& = \ln((1)(2)(3)\cdots (x-1)(x)) \\
& = \ln(x!)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

[Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) gives that

$$\ln(x!) = x\ln(x) - x + O(\ln(x)) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

You thus have, since $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x} = 0$, that

$$\frac{\sum_{z=1}^{x} \ln (z)}{x} = \frac{x\ln(x) - x + O(\ln(x))}{x} \to \ln(x) - 1 \; \text{ as } \; x \to \infty \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer @John Omielan. It was super helpful, especially linking to Stirling's approximation.

Comment: this answer is insanely circular. stirling's approximation is proven by using (1) and approximating the sum on the LHS of (1) by an integral

Comment: @mathworker21 For the answer to be circular means some earlier stage uses Stirling's approximation. However, the only thing I use is the standard logarithmic property that, as I stated, $\ln(x) + \ln(y) = \ln(xy)$, which does *not* in any way depend on Stirling's approximation. The use of this property is repeated multiple times to get $\ln(x!)$. Even if a proof of Stirling's approximation uses the same standard logarithmic property, it still does not make the answer circular.

Comment: @JohnOmielan "For the answer to be circular means some earlier stage uses Stirling's approximation." What the heck... Did you see what I commented?? You used Stirling to prove something that is used to prove Stirling

Comment: @mathworker21 There are other means of proving Stirling's formula which do not rely on approximating the $\log$ of $n!$.

Comment: @Gary what u just said is the correct response to my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, the sums $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$ can be approximated with $\int_1^n f(x) dx $.

Another approach:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \log k -  \log n= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \log \frac{k}{n}$$
and the latter is a Riemann sum for the function $\log x$ on $(0,1]$, so the limit will be the (improper) Riemann integral of this function $\int_{0_{+}}^1 \log x\, dx = -1$.